# Am I wasting bandwidth if I don't change database connection to 'localhost' after deploying to server

Tags: php, linux, apache, server

When I develop and already have a live database I connect my project to it.

- server: www.myserver.com
- user: my_user
- password: my_password
- database: my_database

If i use those settings to the server, will it be smart enough to determine this is the localhost instead of setting a connection through the web to its own location, hence wasting bandwidth?

Or should I always, always change it to

- server: localhost
- user:  root
- password:
- database: my_database

?

Answer (score 0):

Preferably the database will listen to localhost connections only (or LAN internal IPs if it is a dedicated DB), so you'll have to use `localhost` to connect to it anyway. This is a simple method to make your service more secure.

You won't waste bandwidth if you still use the server's external name or IP, if it is configured on the server itself (and not on a NAT, firewall or load balancer device) - the host OS will realize this traffic should go via the loopback network device (host OS internal traffic). If the public address is configured on a network device instead, the configuration will cause extra internal network traffic on your LAN.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR It will be smart if your DNS is correct.

If you use "localhost" the mysql libraries will actually try to find a local unix socket and not use any TCP connection.  If you want to use TCP on localhost you must use 127.0.0.1

Will you use any of your metered hosting traffic?  Well, that's another question.  If the IP address of the the name "www.servername.com" is the same as any of your ethernet devices, then the traffic won't leave your machine.  However, on some cloud hosting setups, this isn't always the case and your traffic might leave your machine to the closest router and then come back.

```
dig www.servername.com
....
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.servername.com.      1799    IN      A       123.456.78.90


/sbin/ifconfig

 eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ....
           inet addr:123.456.78.90  ... <--- same, so OS will redirect to lo
```

You can influence the IP returned for hosts by editing the /etc/hosts file on GNU/Linux distros (I think all POSIX distro... not sure on that).  You can enter:

```
  127.0.0.1  www.servername.com
```

To force the server to use local connections when it tries to connect to www.servername.com.  But, not that this will still use TCP connections and not Unix sockets like a setting of "localhost" would.